# Doctors or Doctor's

Tags: apostrophe

Is it doctors or doctor's in the following sentence.

Having been privy to the pivotal role his doctor's played in his recovery, I have become driven to help others do the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What do you think is the difference between the two of them?

> Doctor's

You can see that there is an apostrophe, so it's talking about someone owning something.

> Doctors

You can see that there is an s, meaning that it's plural.

Which one do you think fits best in that sentence?

Does the doctor own "played"? Or are there many doctors who "played"?

Comment: In my view, If it were "his doctors" it would be "doctor's". It it the sentence just read "the role doctors played in his recovery" without the word "his" i'm inclined to think it would be doctors.

Comment: @GeorgeK - Why does inserting/removing "his" change the number of doctors and change "played" from a verb to a noun?

Comment: Doesn't his add possession i.e. the doctors then belong to him?

Comment: @GeorgeK - "Doctor's" is basically an adjective which identifies stuff owned by a single doctor.